# Can't figure out how to add Follow up Intents in my bot

Tags: artificial-intelligence, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to understand how to create a conversational bot with API.AI but I don't know how to add Follow Up intents in my dialog.
In the tutorial provided by the API.AI website they say that there should be a button like that:

[image: From API.AI website, doc section]

But in the UI provided when I log in, I see something like that:

[image: From the API.AI console]

So as you can see there is no button

Should I pay for having this essential feature?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using a language besides English? Follow up intents are not available in any version besides English.

Comment: yes, I am using Italian. I can't believe there are not supported. Is there another way to simulate follow up intents?

Comment: I would recommend using English if you want anything close to follow up-intents without significant leg work with webhooks. If you want the Italian for the small talk agent or other prebuilt agents, it is best to build an Italian agent and export all the intents to import them into an English agent.

Comment: why? Would not make matching problems?